# How can I view foreign languages in Chromium?

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

I just installed the [minimal version](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) of Ubuntu. (To be specific, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise Pangolin" 32-bit.) This version does not have all the tools that are usually avaialble in normal Ubuntu.

During installation, I chose "Lubuntu minimal installation", then later I installed LXDE as my desktop manager.

I have Chromium already installed, but it cannot view any language fonts other than English. How can I change this so that I can view any languages on my Chromium?

I want to keep everything minimal, so I want to enable this without installing unnecessary features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command to install a specific language:

```
sudo apt-get install language-support-xx
```

where *xx* would be the code for the language that you want to install.

Say for example for English you will use

```
sudo apt-get install language-support-en
```

and for French or Lithuanian you can respectively use:

```
sudo apt-get install language-support-fr
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install language-support-lt
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you late, but thank you for your answer!